# Alternative inverse calculation of the beta function of scipy.stats

Tags: python, scipy, beta

I discovered a bug in the implementation of the beta.ppf function in scipy.stats. It has already been confirmed and marked as a defect in their bug reproting system.

However, currently I need to calculate the confidence intervals of a beta distribution and therefore I need the inverse of the beta function. Since I cannot rely on the current version of beta.ppf I need an alternative for Python. Preferably I do not want to implent the function on my own.

Does anybody know a function that can replace the beta.ppf function from scipy.stats?

Comment: For those interested, here's the issue: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/3761

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I created a workaround by using the c++ boost library which implements a version of the beta distribution. In order to use it you have to install the boost library and compile it. Afterwards you can use it by using the following code:

betainv.cpp

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <boost/math/distributions/beta.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

class betainvClass {
    public: double betainv(double p, double a, double b);
};

double betainvClass::betainv(double p, double a, double b) { 
    return boost::math::ibeta_inv(a, b, p);
}

// Expose classes and methods to Python
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(betainv) {
    class_<betainvClass> ("create_betainv_instance")
        .def("betainv", &betainvClass::betainv)
    ;
}
```

Makefile:

```
TARGET = betainv
PYTHON_INC = /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
PYTHON_LIB = /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config
BOOST_INC = /usr/local/include
BOOST_LIB = /usr/local/lib

$(TARGET).so: $(TARGET).o
    g++ -shared -Wl \
    $(TARGET).o -L$(BOOST_LIB) -lboost_python \
    -L$(PYTHON_LIB) -lpython2.7 \
    -o $(TARGET).so

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).cpp
    g++ -I$(PYTHON_INC) -I$(BOOST_INC) -c $(TARGET).cpp

clean:
    rm -f *.o *.a *.so *~ core
```

Python example file:

```
import betainv

beta = betainv.create_betainv_instance()
print "0.25, 0.0342, 170 -> " + str(beta.betainv(0.25, 0.0342, 170))
print "0.25, 0.0342, 171 -> " + str(beta.betainv(0.25, 0.0342, 171))
print "0.25, 0.0342, 172 -> " + str(beta.betainv(0.25, 0.0342, 172))
```

BTW a further comment. I did a speed test and ran the method 1000 time. First using scipy and then my boost implementation. These are the results in milliseconds:

```
required time scipy = 295.145019531
required time c++   = 7.68383789062
```

boost c++ implementation is roughly 42 time quicker.